# How does MaxLengthAttribute measure length?

Tags: c#, sql-server, validation, utf-8, utf-16

How exactly does the [MaxLengthAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute?view=net-5.0) measure the length of a string? Is it based on bytes in `UTF-16` as C# strings are `UTF-16`? So if my SQL server uses an `UTF-8` collation there could be situations where SQL Server and C# have different opinions about whether a string length is e.g. `<= 100`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it based on bytes in UTF-16 as C# strings are UTF-16

No, it's the number of characters in the `string` object, i.e. the number returned by the `Length` property of the `string`.

For example, a `string` with a value of "abc" has a `Length` of 3 and is represented by 3 bytes in UTF-8 and 6 bytes in UTF-16.

A `string` with a value of "åäö" also has a `Length` of 3 despite being represented by 6 bytes in both UTF-8 and UTF-16.

So it refers the number of `char` elements in the, or the length of the, `string`.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute doesn't measure the length of a string, it just specifies a limit for the string's Length property, which is [clearly documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.length?view=net-5.0) as the number of characters.